# How do I save the owner of a group in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js, koa, sequelize-cli

I am working with Sequelize and Koa. I created both a User and a Group model using the Sequelize-CLI. They have a Many-to-Many association between each other. I want to store which user is the owner of the group is by using his UUID. Do I create another another association using a One-To-Many association (1 User is the owner of 0 or more groups). I wouldn't know how to go about making this association on top of the many-to-many. Or do I just store the UUID of the User in my Group model? What would be the best way to go about this. Thanks!

I searched for an example online with a similar situation but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

If a group can have the one and only owner then it's obvious that you need to add something like `ownerId` to the `Group` and add associations like these ones:

```
User.hasMany(Group, { as: 'OwnedGroups', foreignKey: 'ownerId' })
Group.belongsTo(User, { as: 'Owner', foreignKey: 'ownerId' }
```